# Windows Server Web.config Strip Index Filename

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am using the following web.config file to redirect the non-www version of a site to the www version.  However, I would also like to have it strip the file name of the index file as well.

**For example:**
redirecting www.example.com/index.html to www.example.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Edit:**

<strike>Here is my updated config file.  But, its causing a 500 error, now.</strike>

See CodingGorilla's answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get rid of the `index.html` after the redirect, drop the `{R:1}`.  But then you will need to modify that rule so that it triggers *only* for /index.html requests and create a new rule that triggers on other pages that includes the `{R:1}` so that requests for example.com/mypage.html will still get redirected properly.

**Edit:**

**Edit #2**

**And the final answer is!**

Based on our chat conversation, I think this is the final rule set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="index\.htm(?:l)?" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example\.com$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```